# How to delete rows from a csv file based on a list values from another file?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, grep

I have two files:

`candidates.csv`:

```
id,value
1,123
4,1
2,5
50,5
```

`blacklist.csv`:

```
1
2
5
3
10
```

I'd like to remove all rows from `candidates.csv` in which the first column (`id`) has a value contained in `blacklist.csv`. `id` is always numeric. In this case I'd like my output to look like this:

```
id,value
4,1
50,5
```

So far, my script for identifying the duplicate lines looks like this:

```
cat candidates.csv | cut -d \, -f 1 | grep -f blacklist.csv -w
```

This gives me the output

```
1
2
```

Now I somehow need to pipe this information back into `sed`/`awk`/`gawk`/... to delete the duplicates, but I don't know how. Any ideas how I can continue from here? Or is there a better solution altogether? My only restriction is that it has to run in bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about the following:

```
 awk -F, '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' blacklist.csv candidates.csv
```

**How does this work?**

An awk program is a series of pattern-action pairs, written as:

```
condition { action }
condition { action }
...
```

where `condition` is typically an expression and `action` a series of commands. Here, the first condition-action pairs read:

- `(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}` if the total record count `NR` equals the record count of the file `FNR` (i.e. if we are reading the first file), store all values in array `a` and skip to the next record (do not do anything else)
- `!($1 in a)` if the first field is not in the array `a` then perform the default action which is print the line. This will only work on the second file as the condition of the first condition-action pair does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not too concerned about the order of the lines in your `candidates.csv` file you could use the following:

```
join -v 1 -t, <(sort -t, candidates.csv) <(sort blacklist.csv)
```

The `-v 1` requests all the lines from the first file (the sorted `candidates.csv`) which do not match on the first field with the second file (the `blacklist.csv`).  The `-t,` just sets the comma as a separator.

If you're concerned about the header line in the `candidates.csv` file you could strip it before the sorting or change the order.

Comment: Here's a way to keep the header: `{ IFS= read -r header; echo "$header"; join -t, -v1 <(sort) <(sort blacklist.csv); } < candidates.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` and `grep` together to get the output

```
$ sed -e 's/[0-9]+/&\,/g' blacklist.csv > filter.csv
$ grep -Fvf filter.csv candidates.csv
id,value
4,1
50,5
```

`sed` command adds a `,` to each `id` and output to a `filter.csv`. `E` is to interprete regex in MacOSX/FreeBSD, same as `-r`  in GNU `sed`.

`grep` uses the option `f` to compare between files, then remove the lines using `v`. `F` is for fixed string.